# Not able to open more than 2 tabs using webdrivderio

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to three tabs using webdriverIO v5. Here is the sample code.

```
browser.newWindow("https://www.google.com");
browser.newWindow("https://www.amazon.com");
browser.newWindow("https://www.paypal.com");
```

The test runs successfully but instead of opening third tab for paypal, it reloads second tab with paypal. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sort this out via `window.open()` using JavaScript insertion in WebdriverIO.

```
browser.execute((url) => {
      window.open(url);
    }, "http://twitter.com");
```

See this example I've put together... It will open four different tabs (I am using Chrome) and switch to them.

```
describe("tabs", () => {
  it("multiple browser tabs / windows", () => {
    // open url
    browser.url("https://google.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.newWindow("https://webdriver.io");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.execute((url) => {
      window.open(url);
    }, "http://yahoo.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.execute((url) => {
      window.open(url);
    }, "http://twitter.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.switchWindow("google.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.switchWindow("webdriver.io");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.switchWindow("yahoo.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
browser.switchWindow("twitter.com");
    browser.pause(2000);
  });
});
```

I've also wrote a short article in case other guys face the same challenge, [here](https://medium.com/tagmalogic/webdriverio-open-multiple-browser-tabs-1882fbfc7e89).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you know why new window doesn't do it? Isn't that equivalent of window.open?

Comment: I dont know why `newWindow` does not work I was just trying to help you in case you are stuck.

Comment: @Raju, did the solution that I proposed work? If so, would you like to accept the answer? `newWindow` might be a separate topic all together or maybe open an issue for WebdriverIO?

Comment: Hi, I am not the one who asked the actual question. I was just curious about something in your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @ChanChow did you get a chance to test?

Comment: @Miha Thanks for posting back with a solution. I would try that out and let you know if that works.